# Different Results when assigning an expression to a variable and running it in the JavaScript REPL environment

Tags: javascript, type-coercion

I am currently trying to develop a deeper understanding of JavaScript type coercion. While playing around with the node REPL environment, I encountered the statements `[]+{}` and `let x = []+{}.` After executing the second statement, the variable x holds the value `undefined`, although I expected that the expression evaluates to `'[object Object]'` in both statements.

What causes this difference?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this.  In my Node REPL, in my browser console, etc. the value of `x` is always `'[object Object]'`.  How are you observing the value?

Comment: What happens if you type `x` after that `let` declaration?

Comment: `let y = 3` results in `undefined` as well. You have to type the variable to get it's value `y` results in `3`. I guess that's because statements return nothing and `let ...` is a statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `let` statement returns `undefined`, not variable value. To retrieve variable value, you have to type the variable name.

```js
let x = [] + {};
// undefined
x;
// "[object Object]"
```